# Conditional correlation formula in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the correlations for the funds below. The below example is simplified example and in reality there are more than 100 funds. Is there a formula which would allow me to calculate the correlation conditional on the Fund.

I have already tried using the a formula combining "CORREL" and "IF" but doesnt work. The correlation for Fund A and Benchmark should be 1.0, not -0.23.
The -0.23 correlation corresponds to ALL fund returns vs benchmark returns, not an individual fund.

[image]

[image]

When exiting the formula using Ctrl-shift-enter, the correlation is calculated correctly for the first fund. However, the formula fails to calculate the correlation for the two remaining funds:

[image]

Comment: what version are you using?  If it is not Office 365 then the formula must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode to force an array entry.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, Ctrl-Shift-Enter calculates the correlation correctly for the Fund A. However, the formula stops working when trying to calculate the correlation for the two remaining funds. I'll add a picture to the original post to show in more detail the issue

Comment: Try `{=CORREL(IF($G1=A:A,C:C),(IF($G1=A:A,D:D))}`. The `{}`indicate an array formula, so enter with ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: @MG92 thanks a lot! It works! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Btw. Try to avoid using full column references. This could increase the processing time dramatically. You could use `{=CORREL(IF($G2=A$2:A$50000,C$2:C$50000),(IF($G1=A$2:A$50000,D$2:D$50000))}`, change 50000 to the rows needed